# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal.getHttpUrlChecked

Tags: java, retrofit, fullcontact, okhttp

I am getting this error while trying to hit FullContact API server. I am using okhttp 2.7.5 and okhttp-urlconnection 2.7.5 and retrofit 1.9.0.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal.getHttpUrlChecked(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl;
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:339)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:324)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:392)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:527)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.fullcontact.api.libs.fullcontact4j.http.FCUrlClient.readResponse(FCUrlClient.java:148)
        at com.fullcontact.api.libs.fullcontact4j.http.FCUrlClient.execute(FCUrlClient.java:91)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes up only when you have incompatible versions of libraries /jars used for your code compilation than what you are using for runtime execution dependency.

Make sure you have the right version both places.

It could also be a case that you are compiling your source code by explicitly adding your library jars.
But at run time the server is loading the library class from a different version jar which is not having the required method.

Comment: Thanks. Error went away once i deleted the older version of jar from my lirary.